# Swift error: cannot convert value of type 'Int32' to expected argument type 'Int32'

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to write a pair of functions to convert a `String` into a `[UInt8]` byte array and back again.

As part of the function that goes from `[UInt8] -> String`, I'm attempting to convert a single `Int32` into a `Character`.

```swift
let num : Int32 = 5
let char = Character(_builtinUnicodeScalarLiteral: num)
```

But I'm getting this strange error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'Int32' to expected argument type 'Int32'
let char = Character(_builtinUnicodeScalarLiteral: num)
                                                   ^~~
```

EDIT: I managed to write my functions using different code, but I'm still curious about the meaning of the error.

Comment: try not to setup int32 swift should recognize by var data. let num = 5

Comment: Edited my answer to also explain the error.

Comment: check my answer. to 'convert' [UInt8]->String and back you can use reduce and map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use that constructor this way

```
let num: Int32 = 5
let g = Character(_builtinUnicodeScalarLiteral: num.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using types, methods and initializers prefixed with `_` as they are private and an implementation detail. The same goes for anything with `builtin` in the name.

`Character` expects a `UnicodeScalar` which can be constructed from a `UInt32` (and also `UInt8`):

```
let num : UInt32 = 65
let g = Character(UnicodeScalar(num))
print(g) // prints 'A'
```

Your error occurrs because you pass an `Int32` while Swift expects an `Builtin.Int32`, which is a different type. The error message just isn't clear enough.

Comment: it is not declared as private, and is well documented in Apple docs

Comment: @user3441734 well they're listed in their docs but there's no explanation. They're just not intended to be used by anything except Swift itself.